# PHP php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, fopen, getaddrinfo

I am having DNS issues with a certain target domain. I am using `fopen()` (but same issue with other functions) to retreive an image, but I get this error: 
`Warning: fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known`

I am able to ping or nslookup the domain from the command prompt, but for some reason php throws this error. When I try `fopen('http://www.google.com', r);` or other domains, all goes fine. But above mentioned domain simply won't resolve with PHP. I have flushed the DNS, restarted Apache, but still no luck..

I have tried with:

- Windows 7, Apache 2.2 PHP 5.3.6
- Windows server 2008r2, Apache 2.2 PHP 5.3.6

What can cause this single domain to not resolve?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo - and you should ask your system-administrator about the issue.

Comment: Perhaps the domain really doesn't exist, or the target domain's DNS server is unavailable to your server. You could try `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear out your cache, though.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of the URL? (you can strip the domain name)

Comment: If you were under Linux, I'd say: dump the name of the file, then try to "wget" that file. But Windows....

Comment: @Narf, I can't resolve the domain at all. Even at it's root. From the CMD there are no problems resolving the domain. From PHP I can resolve other domains though.. Peculiar..
DNS was flushed already.

Comment: @Richard, OK ... if even `fopen('http://domain.tld', 'r');` doesn't work - then I guess the URL format shouldn't be the problem. How is the server's internet connection configured? Is it via DHCP, static IP or some other method?

Comment: Hey man, i had the same error, it seems that this was because of an invalid address like: http://localhostmysite instead of http://localhost/mysite. Maybe your issue is caused by a similar problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

IMO it's the different way to resolve a name from the OS and PHP.

Try:

```
echo gethostbyname("host.name.tld");
```

and

```
var_export (dns_get_record ( "host.name.tld") );
```

or

```
$dns=array("8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4");
var_export (dns_get_record ( "host.name.tld" ,  DNS_ALL , $dns ));
```

You should found some DNS/resolver error.

Answer (score 4):

Your "localhost" cannot resolve the name www.google.com, which means your machine doesn't/can't reach a valid dns server.

Try ping google.com on the console of that machine to verify this.

Answer (score 2):

It is more flexible to use `curl` instead of `fopen` and `file_get_content` for opening a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

**Your target domain might refuse to send you information.** This can work as a filter based on browser agent or any other header information. **This is a defense** against bots, crawlers or any unwanted applications.

Answer (score 1):

> getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

The above error is caused due to mistake in Database Host (DB_HOST) in .env file

Open the .env file and Specially check for this env variables

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=database_username
DB_PASSWORD=database_password
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues with this on Windows. I just performed git clone, copied my `.env.example` file to `.env`. updated it, and executed my trusty PHP script to update initial database used for a project. And it failed, and whatever I did, it kept on failing. Out of desperation, I reinstalled MySQL, but that didn't fix things.

Finally, I figured it out. PHP script extracted the settings from `.env` file using `file_get_contents()`, and exploding it using `\n`, but the `.env` file was encoded with CRLF, so my DB_HOST was empty. After I changed the encoding of the `.env` file, everything was fine.

So, my point is, echo the parameters supplied to `mysqli::construct`, and it might be the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

A weird thing I found was that the environment variable `SYSTEMROOT` must be set otherwise `getaddrinfo()` will fail on Windows 10.

Answer (score -4):

What had caused this error on my side was the following line

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';
```

I managed to realize it was the culprit when i added the lines:

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to all my php files.

To solve the `path issue` i canged the offending line to:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
```

Comment: Your original line and "changed" line are the same right now.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem related at all.. Did you also get the message `Warning: fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known` when using `include`?  Pretty sure that's not possible

Comment: I realized that that mistake lead to a myriad of unrelated problems, That;s why i posted it as an answer to many different problems.