# Error #0: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to zf2-api:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )

Tags: php, api, zend-framework

I have been trying to design a Signup Page using a tutorial in a Zend framework 2 Book .Problem is that I am unable to complete signup after running it as  , clicking on register gives a socket error  , which I have no clue.

```
    Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException
    File:
    C:\xampp\htdocs\ZF2AD\Chapter10\client\vendor\zendframework\zend-http\src\Client\Adapter\Socket.php:256
    Message:
    Unable to connect to zf2-api:80 . Error #0: stream_socket_client():unable to connect to zf2-api:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )
```

I am using Api to connect to database.Below is the code for my Apiclient.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Api\Client;

    use Zend\Http\Client;
    use Zend\Http\Request;
    use Zend\Json\Decoder as JsonDecoder;
    use Zend\Json\Json;
    use Zend\Log\Logger;
    use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;

    /**
     * This client manages all the operations needed to interface with the
     * social network API
     *
     * @package default
     */
   class ApiClient {

/**
 * Holds the client we will reuse in this class
 *
 * @var Client
 */
protected static $client = null;

/**
 * Holds the endpoint urls
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected static $endpointHost = 'http://zf2-api';
protected static $endpointWall = '/api/wall/%s';
protected static $endpointFeeds = '/api/feeds/%s';
protected static $endpointSpecificFeed = '/api/feeds/%s/%d';
protected static $endpointUsers = '/api/users';
protected static $endpointGetUser = '/api/users/%s';
protected static $endpointUserLogin = '/api/users/login';

/**
 * Perform an API reqquest to retrieve the data of the wall
 * of an specific user on the social network
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function getWall($username)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . sprintf(self::$endpointWall, $username);
    return self::doRequest($url);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to post content on the wall of an specific user
 *
 * @param string $username 
 * @param array $data 
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function postWallContent($username, $data)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . sprintf(self::$endpointWall, $username);
    return self::doRequest($url, $data, Request::METHOD_POST);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to get the list subscriptions of a username
 *
 * @param string $username 
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function getFeeds($username)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . sprintf(self::$endpointFeeds, $username);
    return self::doRequest($url);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to add a new subscription
 *
 * @param string $username 
 * @param array $postData
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function addFeedSubscription($username, $postData)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . sprintf(self::$endpointFeeds, $username);
    return self::doRequest($url, $postData, Request::METHOD_POST);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to remove a subscription
 *
 * @param string $username 
 * @param array $postData
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function removeFeedSubscription($username, $feedId)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . sprintf(self::$endpointSpecificFeed, $username, $feedId);
    return self::doRequest($url, null, Request::METHOD_DELETE);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to add a new user
 *
 * @param array $postData
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function registerUser($postData)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . self::$endpointUsers;
    return self::doRequest($url, $postData, Request::METHOD_POST);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to get the basic data of a user
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function getUser($username)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . sprintf(self::$endpointGetUser, $username);
    return self::doRequest($url, null, Request::METHOD_GET);
}

/**
 * Perform an API request to authenticate a user
 *
 * @param array $postData Array containing username and password on their respective keys
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 */
public static function authenticate($postData)
{
    $url = self::$endpointHost . self::$endpointUserLogin;
    return self::doRequest($url, $postData, Request::METHOD_POST);
}

/**
 * Create a new instance of the Client if we don't have it or 
 * return the one we already have to reuse
 *
 * @return Client
 */
protected static function getClientInstance()
{
    if (self::$client === null) {
        self::$client = new Client();
        self::$client->setEncType(Client::ENC_URLENCODED);
    }

    return self::$client;
}

/**
 * Perform a request to the API
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $postData
 * @param Client $client
 * @return Zend\Http\Response
 * @author Christopher
 */
protected static function doRequest($url, array $postData = null, $method = Request::METHOD_GET)
{
    $client = self::getClientInstance();
    $client->setUri($url);
    $client->setMethod($method);

    if ($postData !== null) {
        $client->setParameterPost($postData);
    }

    $response = $client->send();

    if ($response->isSuccess()) {
        return JsonDecoder::decode($response->getBody(), Json::TYPE_ARRAY);
    } else {
        $logger = new Logger;
        $logger->addWriter(new Stream('data/logs/apiclient.log'));
        $logger->debug($response->getBody());
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

}

Refining the error  , I got to know that this is the main error in all errors

```
    stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

I have tried solutions provided in similar questions , but they didnt helped . If anyone knows about it please help.

Comment: I have checked similar looking question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210099/php-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known

Comment: It's failing to resolve `zf2-api`. Is this the hostname for your ZF2 app? If so the tutorial should have told you to add an entry to your hosts file. That's the step you've missed.

Comment: thats the name for my api developed for the app to connect to database

Comment: I have added entry to https-vhosts.conf which is in the folder xampp/apache/conf/extra

Comment: When I check Socket.php , at the path specified in the message  , there is a block of code which is causing error

      if (!$this->socket) {
                $this->close();
                throw new AdapterException\RuntimeException(
                    sprintf(
                        'Unable to connect to %s:%d%s',
                        $host,
                        $port,
                        ($error ? ' . Error #' . $error->getCode() . ': ' . $error->getMessage() : '')
                    ),
                    0,
                    $error
                );
            }

Comment: `https-vhosts.conf` is not the file that needs changing. You need to add an entry to your system hosts file. On Windows I think it's something like `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: @TimFountain : And how to add entry to hosts file? I am using localhost with xampp which doesnt have any ip settings like cpanel of a hosting server.

Comment: Edit the file - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/ If xampp is hosting your API as well, you want to add an entry to the host file to point that hostname at your local machine: `zf2-api 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: That means I just add an entry to the the last line of the file

Just like 

        127.0.0.1       localhost
 ::1                  localhost

Comment: Yup - sorry, the IP and hostname were the wrong way around in my comment above.

Comment: I did that  , it doesnt shows any error but doesnt do anything and there is still nothing in database

Comment: @TimFountain I tried to edit the file and the error got away but on submitting sign up form  , nothing happens  , and nothing gets stored in database