# script tag is not working in php code it not creat an alert form validation

Tags: javascript

This is my code ....script tag is not working in this php code for form validation.

```
           $get_email = "select * from users where user_email='$email'";
           $run_email = mysqli_query($con,$get_email);
           $check  = mysqli_num_rows($run_email);
              if($check==1){
               echo "<script>alert('Email is already registered!')</script>";
                exit(); 
                }
           if(strlen($pass)<8){
              echo  "<script>alert('password should be 8 character!')</script>";
               exit();
               }
```

Comment: How exactly is this failing?  Be specific, we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: check your console for any errors

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , i think you need to set the javascript tag if you are using php to run it, didnt understand too much your question ,but , i think could be something like this:

```
<?php 
echo "<script>
        alert('Email is already registered!');
        exit();
      </script> ";

  if( strlen($pass) ) {
    echo "<script>alert('password should be 8 character!');
          exit();
          </script>" 
  }
  else { 
   $insert = "insert into users 
                (user_name,
                user_pass,
                user_email,
                user_id,user_country,
                user_gender,
                user_birthday,
                user_image,user_regis ,
                user_login date,status)

            values ('$name',
            '$pass','$email',
            '$country',
            '$Gender',
            '$user_birthday',
            'default.jpg',
            '$date', 
            '$status',
            '$posts')"; 
            $run_insert = mysqli_query($con,$insert); 
    if($run_insert){ 
        echo "<script> alert('Regisration successfull') </script>"; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

i really recommend to you , USE ajax call to make the selection and validation of email!

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\wamp\www\Social_network\functions\functions.php on line 3
Call Stack   (this error come )

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\wamp\www\Social_network\functions\functions.php on line 3
Call Stack      ()this is the error

Comment: You have problems with some URL, or your localhost, think could se here,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210099/php-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known