# Retrieve XML information from url with PHP

Tags: php, xml, http, httprequest

I have this URL witch in my web browser leads me to a XML feed.

http://mandeo.meteogalicia.es/thredds/ncss/grid/modelos/WRF_HIST/d03/2016/04/wrf_arw_det_history_d03_20160413_0000.nc4?var=temp&latitude=41.15&longitude=-8.6166667&accept=xml

The problem is i can't retrieve it's information using cURL or file_get_contents. The curious thing was that yesterday at my home i could retrieve it using this block of code:

```
if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($this->url_request))===false){
            echo "Error fetching XML\n";
        } else {
           libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
           $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
           if (!$data) {
               echo "Error loading XML\n";
               foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                   echo "\t", $error->message;
               }
           } else {
              print_r($data);
           }
        }*/
```

Today the same block of code in the same computer enviromment but in a different network throws me this error message:

> Message:
>   file_get_contents(http://mandeo.meteogalicia.es/thredds/ncss/grid/modelos/WRF_HIST/d03/2016/04/wrf_arw_det_history_d03_20160413_0000.nc4?var=temp%2Cprec%2Cu%2Cv%2Cdir%2Cvisibility&point=true&latitude=41.15&longitude=-8.6166667&accept=xml):
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

Anyone has any ideas to workaround this?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried to access to this url from a web browser in your current network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP php\_network\_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210099/php-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known)

Comment: @Arnau Lacambra yes and it leads to me a xml feed page.

Comment: it's a DNS problelm in my docker container! God dammit. All morning on this. :)
Thank you!